# How to write postman pre-request script for Post request with a predefined value in postman?

Tags: postman

postman post request

URL:

```
{{url}}oauth/access_token
```

data given in 'form data' format

```
user_id_1_phn


written Pre-request Script

{

    "user_id_1_phn": "{{user_id_1_phn}}"

}
```

after loading csv file, when runner executed 
postman is showing message like:

> There was an error in evaluating the pre-request script: Unexpected
>   Token

Comment: what's your pre-request script?

Comment: {

    "user_id_1_phn": "{{user_id_1_phn}}"

}